# Error in confint: Starting values violate bounds

Tags: r, lme4

I would like to estimate the confidence intervals of a model created with lmer. But I'm having some problems. When I run the confint, an error appears:

```
    Error in (function (par, fn, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, control = list(),  : Starting values violate bounds
```

Could anyone please explain to me why this is happening and how I could solve it?

Below is my code. I have two levels for 'rate' (high, low), and two levels for 'cover' (yes, no), while I have four conditions (1, 2, 3, 4).

```
library(MASS);library(lme4)
contrasts(datafile$rate) <-contr.sdif(2)
contrasts(datafile$cover) <-contr.sdif(2)
contr.lmer1 = lmer(ldepvar ~ rate*cover + (1 + condition|pp) + (1 + condition|stim), data = datafile)
print(contr.lmer1, corr=FALSE)
confint(contr.lmer1)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I am using library(lme4).

Comment: You should run `traceback()` to see which function is being called with insufficient starting values. If I'm correct that the class of the contr.lmer object is `merMod`, you could try setting `method="Wald"` to see if the problem is occurring the the `profile()`-call that is made by the `confint.merMod` function when using the 'profile' method.

Comment: any chance of a reproducible example?  Did you get any warnings when you ran the initial model?